# how can I fix this problem about building springboot in docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, jpa, amazon-ec2

I often use stackoverflow these days.I wish you can fix my error
please help me :(
I'm using ec2 (ubuntu),docker, nginx(https using certbot), springboot, jpa, springsecurity.
I thought it is because of jre. but it doesn't work when I installed jre and jdk.
here is my error code

i guess keyword is `Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server` or not t.t

```
2022-08-07 07:48:41.045  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2022-08-07 07:48:41.089  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-07 07:48:41.091  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-07 07:48:41.107  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-07 07:48:41.109  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-07 07:48:41.123  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-07 07:48:41.149 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at com.jangbo.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:10) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [app.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) [app.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [app.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) [app.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1077) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:275) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1074) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

**`Dockerfile`**

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM java:8

ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "/app.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

**`Application.properties`**

```
#it will be set build date by gradle. if this value is @build.date@, front-end is development mode
build.date=@build.date@
server.port=8080
server.address=*myserver*
#server.address=localhost
server.servlet.contextPath=/
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
# Enable http encoding support.
server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true
# Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
server.servlet.encoding.force=true

# Swagger
springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER


#database
#API ?? ? sql?? ??
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#MySQL ?? ??
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://*myserver*:3306/jangbo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*dbnname*?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&rewriteBatchedStatements=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.username=root
spring.datasource.hikari.password=*password*
#MySQL ?? ??
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy


spring.mustache.suffix: .html
#logging
#logging.level.root=INFO
#logging.level.com.samsung.security=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.apache.tiles=INFO
#logging.level.org.springframework.boot=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
#
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true
#logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug


#Redis
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=*myserver*
#spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379

# JWT Secret Key
spring.jwt.secret=*contents of key*
```

I edited my post

thank you.

Comment: Hi Seol and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please share some more details, for example, how does your dockerfile and server.xml file look like. By posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) others will be more likely to be able to help

Comment: hi I edited my post. actually I still don't know my problem exactly. and..  when I changed server address to localhost . error is gone although site doesn't work :(